# Angular component custom style from parents

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, shadow-dom

I would like to enable custom CSS variables to customize a component in my Ionic application.

I read about using custom CSS properties but I can't figure out how it works.

From [Angular official docs:](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#authoring-a-component-to-support-customization)

> Authoring a component to support customization
> As component author, you can explicitly design a component to accept customization in one of four different ways.
>
> 1. Use CSS Custom Properties (recommended)
>    You can define a supported customization API for your component by defining its styles with CSS Custom Properties, alternatively known as CSS Variables. Anyone using your component can consume this API by defining values for these properties, customizing the final appearance of the component on the rendered page.
>
> While this requires defining a custom property for each customization point, it creates a clear API contract that works in all style encapsulation modes.

I tried using `@HostBinding`:

```
@HostBind('style.--custom-property') customProp;
```

But I don't understand how to apply the css property to my component from one of its parents.

Comment: There are some examples here: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-manipulating-css-custom-properties-style-binding. Does that help?

Comment: Not really... For example using <div [style.--css-custom-property-name]="template-expression"></div> I don't understand how to set a custom property from parent component.. I would like to do like inside Ionic Framework, if customizable component is <my-cmp></my-cmp> I want to write <div style="--custom-color:red"><my-cmp></my-cmp></div> and my-cmp should be red..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found how to solve this:

Child component

```css
.cmp-class {
  color: var(--custom-color, red);
}
```

```html
<div class="cmp-class"><p>Hello</p></div>
```

Parent component

```css
child-cmp {
  --custom-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<child-cmp></child-cmp>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-deep, for example from parent component use:

```
child-cmp ::ng-deep .cmp-class {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Although the answer is correct, ng-deep is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) and therefore it is preferable not to use it.